# How to create Rules for dynamically generated fields

Tags: php, jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

http://www.kosherjellyfish.com/test/index.php

I'm using the [jQuery Validation Plugin][1] for my form.

I have form fields within tables which are dynamically-generated: the number of tables is dependent on how many the users has created. A sample of the table below:

```
<?php (for $i=1;$i<3;$i++){?> 
<table class="coauthortable">

    <tr>
       <td>Title * </td>
       <td>
          <select name="contactTitle<? echo $i;?> ">
          <option value="">Select Title</option>
          <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
          <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
          <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
          <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
          <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
          <option value="Professor">Professor</option>
         </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>First Name *</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="contactFirstName<? echo $i;?>" style="width:280px;" /></td>
    </tr>


    <!--Actual program has more rows-->

</table>
<?php }  ?>
```

I wish to add validation rules to the dynamically generated input fields: it seems like I can't do it properly in the Validation Method itself, because I do not know the actual number of fields that's going to be generated:

```
$("#papersubmitform").validate(
        {
        rules:{
            //Can't add rules this way as I do not know how many rows will be generated. 
            contactTitle: {required: true},
            contactFirstName: { required:true},

});
```

I've tried to add rules that'll be added on $(document).ready(function() once the page is loaded, but it does not seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".coauthortable").each(function(i){ 
            $(this).find(":input").each(function(){ 
                $(this).rules("add",{required:true});
            });         
});

  $("#papersubmitform").validate();         


});
```

Does anyone have any recommendations on what I should do to add the rules to dynamically-created elements?

I have created a sample page here in my own server... http://www.kosherjellyfish.com/test/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do that in the opposite order:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#papersubmitform").validate();         

   $(".coauthortable").each(function(i){ 
            $(this).find(":input").each(function(){ 
                $(this).rules("add",{required:true});
            });         
    });
});
```